# Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2013 Requirements and Licenses

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, ms-release-management

We are trying to figure out if we can make use of Release Management for our Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment needs.

It says that the Release Management Client requires VS 2013 Premium/Ultimate/Test. Does it mean it's only the person who is configuring the build needs to have such version and other developers can still use their VS 2013 Pro?

Does the Release Management Server for TFS 2013 has it's own license which is different from Microsoft Deployment Agent 2013?

Does the product now supports Visual Studio Online? If it helps, we have a TFS proxy and build server in-house.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing of a third-party tool, and not about programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. Licensing questions should be addressed to the author/vendor of the software product concerned or to an attorney licensed to practice in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the only technical question you asked: Release Management does not support Visual Studio Online at the moment.

You can read the licensing information here, which pretty clearly answers the questions you have:
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/how-to-buy-release-management-vs.aspx